# Write a cmd batch file to initialize the database

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-8, mysql-8.0

Windows 8 64-bit. MySQL 8.0.11

Write a cmd batch file to initialize the database.

```
@ECHO OFF
start "" mysqlsh root@localhost --sql --password=pa55word
```

As a result, it connects to server. How can I execute a script-file .sql?

Comment: @somebadhat, thanks, i got access to host , i want to create database from script `base.sql`

Comment: @somebadhat already

Comment: @somebadhat Ver 8.0.11 for Windows on AMD64 - for MySQL 8.0.11 (MySQL Community Server (GPL))

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

```
@ECHO OFF
start "" mysqlsh root@localhost --sql --password=javajava --file=c:/script.sql
```

Thanks for [dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysqlsh.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysqlsh.html) to [@somebadhat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8826818/somebadhat)